# Toggle table rows / Toggle Button after the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to hide and show some rows of my HTML table with a toggle button.
I need to display the toggle button after the table, I only could display the button before my table. How can I custom this ? Ty

```css
/*Use CSS to hide the rows of the table that is next to check box that is next to an element with a class of tableToggle*/
.tableToggle + input[type="checkbox"]:checked + table>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}

/*Hide the checkbox*/
.tableToggle + input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}

/*Button Styling only -- noting important here*/
.tableToggle{
    background-color:#44c767;
    -moz-border-radius:28px;
    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;  
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

```html
<label class="tableToggle" for="cb1">Toggle Rows</label><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1 C1</td>
      <td>R1 C2</td>
      <td>R1 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2 C1</td>
      <td>R2 C2</td>
      <td>R2 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R3 C1</td>
      <td>R3 C2</td>
      <td>R3 C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly do you want to get?

Comment: I want to get a table and a button below, I want to keep the logic with the toggle button, but if the button is below the table, the toggle logic doesn't work. It only works if the button is above the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome!

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    table {
      display: block;
    }

    /*Use CSS to hide the rows of the table that is next to check box that is next to an element with a class of tableToggle*/
    .tableToggle+input[type="checkbox"]:checked+table>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+2) {
      display: none;
    }

    /*Hide the checkbox*/
    .tableToggle+input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
    }

    /*Button Styling only -- noting important here*/
    .tableToggle {
      background-color: #44c767;
      -moz-border-radius: 28px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
      border-radius: 28px;
      border: 1px solid #18ab29;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Arial;
      padding: 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <label class="tableToggle" for="cb1">Toggle Rows</label><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Head 1</th>
          <th>Head 2</th>
          <th>Head 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>R1 C1</td>
          <td>R1 C2</td>
          <td>R1 C3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>R2 C1</td>
          <td>R2 C2</td>
          <td>R2 C3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>R3 C1</td>
          <td>R3 C2</td>
          <td>R3 C3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just cut first line and paste it after table tag.
correct HTML code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1 C1</td>
      <td>R1 C2</td>
      <td>R1 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2 C1</td>
      <td>R2 C2</td>
      <td>R2 C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R3 C1</td>
      <td>R3 C2</td>
      <td>R3 C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<label class="tableToggle" for="cb1">Toggle Rows</label><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

Comment: explain problem right please.

Comment: Doesn't work, my toggle logic display/not display, only works if the button is above the table